# What is actually a 'context' in getServerSideProps(`context`)? - Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

So, my instructor building an application, he told me to use getServerSideProps(`context`).
Since Next.js updated, I want to know what context means and what does it holds? Since the course was outdated, can any please tell me the alternative method? here's my instructor code:
userPage.jsx:

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import React from "react";

const UserPage = () => {
  return <div>User</div>;
};

export default UserPage;
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);
  console.log("sess", session);
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

I tried and searched a lot for this and iam tired for this. **Please Ignore This Question if you think this is Stupid :)**

Answer (score 1):

Context provides information about the request, including matched params for dynamic routes, query parameters, request cookies, and more.

You can find more information about the context parameter in [the official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-server-side-props#context-parameter).

If you'd like to upgrade to use the `/app` directory pattern, you can follow [this migration guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#server-side-rendering-getserversideprops). In short, you'll use React Server Components to directly `fetch` the data you need for your component.

Answer (score 1):

The `context` parameter is a special object that holds various pieces of information related to the current HTTP request being processed. Note that `context` object in each server-side functions (getStaticProps..) is different because their environment is different. `getServerSideProps` runs with every requst.

If you look at the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-server-side-props#context-parameter), each key is related to the HTTP request.

`req` and `res` objects are similar in `express`. Here you do not need to send anything with `res.send` like in `express.js` because Next.js will do it automatically (its response is the rendered component). But you can intervene in and manipulate the `res` object by adding extra headers or cookies.

with `req` you can intervene in incoming request and read the incoming data, headers,cookies etc. so you can check if the user authenticated or not

`params` is useful to read the dynamic part of the page. In dynamic pages, `param` usually refers to `id` of stored data so you fetch the data on the server by using the id